# count total in column based on other columns - R

Tags: r, dataframe

How do I convert the dataframe?

Before:

```
set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame( n = rpois(16, 2),
                  year = rep(2011, 16),
                  month = rep(seq(1,4,1), times = rep(4,4)))
```

After:

```
df1 <- data.frame( n = c(8,11,4,9),
                  year = rep(2011, 4),
                  month = rep(seq(1,4,1)))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think  that what you want is this, using `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  group_by(year, month) %>% 
  summarise(n = sum(n))
# A tibble: 4 x 3
# Groups:   year [1]
   year month     n
  <dbl> <dbl> <int>
1  2011     1     8
2  2011     2    11
3  2011     3     4
4  2011     4     9
```

Comment: Did you set.seed(1)? I got the same as OP.

Comment: @bs93 d'oh - my bad

Comment: Thank you! Very helpful

Answer (score 2):

Using `base R` with `aggregate`

```
aggregate(n ~ ., df, sum)
# year month  n
#1 2011     1  8
#2 2011     2 11
#3 2011     3  4
#4 2011     4  9
```